# How to get the most occured set of objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have two objects.

```
@Entity
class Person extends Model {

    ...
    @OneToOne
    Category category;
}


@Entity 
class Category extends Model {
    ...
}
```

I need to get the 5 most used categories. How can I do that ?

Thanks,

EDIT : Solution

```
List<Object[]> c = Category.find(
    "SELECT p.categorie, count(p.id) FROM Person p " +
    "GROUP BY p.category ORDER BY count(p.category) DESC").fetch(2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JPQL query would be something like this:

```
SELECT p.category, COUNT(p.category)
FROM Person p
GROUP BY p.category
ORDER BY count(p.category) DESC
```

And you'd do query.setMaxResults(5) also.

Comment: group by p.category doesn't work. See https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1615. And I think you would need the count in the select for the order by to work.

Comment: @JB Nizet: OK, the first part is a Hibernate Bug, it *should* work according to the JPA spec, the second part is of course true, which messes up the result type, grrrr.

Comment: Really strange. I combined this answer with the one below and it works. See my edit for more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select category.id, count(person.id) 
from Person person 
inner join person.category category
group by category.id
order by count(person.id) desc
```

And before executing this query, call `setMaxResults(5)` on the Query object.